# How to invoke method from another

Tags: java

I'm trying to do temperature conversion and I know I need to invoke convertTemp in main, but I just don't know what I'm doing. Can someone take a look at this and help me out?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TemperatureConverter {

  public static void convertTemp() {
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       double temperature;
       String temperatureScale = " ";

     if (temperatureScale.equals("f"))
     {    
     // code that converts from Fahrenheit to Celsius 
        temperature = (5/9)*(keyboard.nextDouble() - 32);   
     // and prints the result to the screen  
        System.out.println("The temperature is " + temperature + "degrees celsius");
     }
        //
     else if (temperatureScale.equals("c")) 
     {       
     // code that converts from Celsius to Fahrenheit    
        temperature = 32.0 +(keyboard.nextDouble() * 1.8);
        System.out.println("The temperature is " + temperature + "degrees fahrenheit");
     // and prints the result to the screen 
     } 
     else 
     {    
     // code that outputs a message indicating that an incorrect 
        System.out.println("Error! A valid temperature was not chosen!");   
     // option was selected 
     } 
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("What temeprature number are you trying to find out?"); 
     double keyboardInput = keyboard.nextDouble();


     System.out.println("Type f for Fahrenheit or c for Celsius.");
     String keyboardTempLetter = keyboard.next(); 

   }

  }
 //}
```

Comment: For starters: `temperatureScale` should be an argument to `convertTemp`, passed in from `main`.

Comment: Well, "should be" in the sense that it would improve the code, not that it is required to execute.

Comment: I agree with @LouisWasserman: There is no way that I/O should be part of this method.  It should do one thing: convert temperature from one scale to another.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the user input to the method convertTemp so the method checks it then returns the result or prints it like you did .

Problem is you initialized **temperatureScale** and **temperature** in your method by adding

```
 double temperature;
`String temperatureScale = " "; `
```

So the method used them instead of what the user inserted.

Second problem convertTemp method doesn't receive the userinput

convertTemp(**NOTHING IS RECIVED HERE**).

Third problem you didn't even send the input from main

So first your method should have:

```
convertTemp(String  temperatureScale,double temperature)
```

Then remove the initialization of temperatureScale and temperature as I said above also remove

```
`   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);`
```

From convertTemp since you initialized it in main

Finally call the method in your main method this way :-

```
convertTemp(keyboardInputkeyboardInput,keyboardTempLetter);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me out immensely!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of calling scanner in the convertTemp method, pass the character or string and the number in as an argument. then you'll just need to call the function in your main like this:

```
    convertTemp(double keyboardInput, String keyboardTempLetter);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This really helped me out!